# How to provide library bundles in WSO2 feature definition?

Tags: wso2, osgi, p2

Following the student-manager example I managed to prepare WSO2 features (server + ui + aggregate) and generate a p2 repository.

The aggregate feature fails to install because of missing dependencies, for example my xxx.analyzer component (and later some Apache Commons libraries):

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: My Manager Aggregate Feature 1.0.0 (xxx.mgt.feature.group 1.0.0)
  Missing requirement: xxx.mgt 1.0.0 (xxx.mgt 1.0.0) requires 'package xxx.analyzer 0.0.0' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: My Manager Aggregate Feature 1.0.0 (xxx.mgt.feature.group 1.0.0)
    To: xxx.mgt.server.feature.group [1.0.0]
```

My bundles are installed in the local M2_REPO.
When I directly install them into the WSO2 OSGi Console command line they work properly.

How to include them into the features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `<bundleDef>group.id:bundle.artifact.id</bundleDef>` within the configuration section of the carbon-p2 plugin in the feature pom to include your bundles to a feature. It would be something similar to below.

```
...
<execution>
   <id>p2-feature-generation</id>
   <phase>package</phase>
   <goals>
      <goal>p2-feature-gen</goal>
   </goals>
   <configuration>
      <id>org.wso2.carbon.student.mgt.ui</id>
      ...
      <bundles>
         <bundleDef>org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.student.mgt.stub</bundleDef>
         <bundleDef>org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.student.mgt.ui</bundleDef>
      </bundles>
   </configuration>
</execution>
...
```

If you need to include a feature instead of a bundle, you can use the `<includedFeatureDef>group.id:feature.artifact.id</includedFeatureDef>` in your aggregate feature pom. Examples for both can be found in [this tutorial](http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2014/03/how-to-create-a-feature-from-wso2-carbon-component/).

Comment: When I just added a <bundleDef>, I got an error about unknown version of the package. After adding the standard <dependency> element in the <dependencies> feature was built correctly.

Comment: Another tip: To eliminate issues with transitive dependencies you can use <Embed-Dependency> and <Embed-Transitive> directives as described in [Bundle Plugin for Maven documentation](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-bundle-plugin-bnd.html#ApacheFelixMavenBundlePlugin%28BND%29-Embeddingdependencies)